# Como gerenciar os pagamentos de atualização de sites?

Tags: google-sites

Bom dia,boa tarde ou boa noite pessoal

Eu estou iniciando com freelance na are de desenvolvimento de web sites e ainda estou decidido se vou trabalhar com cobranças mensal para atualização de sites. O problema é  que eu não sei como controlar quem está em dia nós pagamentos.Emissão de boletos. É gostaria de sabe para quem trabalha dessa forma como é que vcs fazem para gerenciar?